# Плавный скроллинг к якорю со слешем

Tags: html, jquery, прокрутка

У меня возникла следующая проблема: не могу настроить плавный скроллинг к якорю со слешем. У меня сайт состоит из двух страниц, три пункта меню находятся на одной странице, один пункт меню переводит на вторую. Слеш в данном случае нужен для того, чтобы я мог свободно перемещаться между страницами (всего их две), в особенности со второй на первою - без слеша это сделать не получается. Я написал следующий код, но он не срабатывает - в консоли тоже ничего не выдает:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function () {
        elementClick = $(this).attr("href");
        elementClick = elementClick.substr(1);
        destination = jQuery(elementClick.split("/")[1]).offset().top;
        if($.browser.safari){
            $('body').animate( { scrollTop: destination }, 1100 );
        }else{
            $('html').animate( { scrollTop: destination }, 1100 );
        }
    return false;
    });
```

Реально ли вообще осуществить такое, или я просто трачу время? Заранее спасибо за ответы!

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="go_to" href="/#about-us">ABOUT US</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="go_to" href="/#about-course">COURSE</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="go_to" href="/#buy-a_course">BUY A COURSE</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="about-us" id="about-us">
  blah blah blah
</div>
<div class="about-us" id="about-course">
  blah blah blah
</div>
<div class="about-us" id="buy-a_course">
  blah blah blah
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Тебе нужно отменить событие по умолчанию.

```
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    elementClick = $(this).attr("href");
    elementClick = elementClick.substr(1);
    destination = jQuery(elementClick.split("/")[1]).offset().top;
    if($.browser.safari){
        $('body').animate( { scrollTop: destination }, 1100 );
    }else{
        $('html').animate( { scrollTop: destination }, 1100 );
    }
return false;
});
```

Comment: спасибо, сработало!